# SQLEXCEPTION in symfony

Tags: postgresql, symfony, xampp, symfony1

what could be the problem of this error? thanks!

[SQLException]
Could not execute query [Native Error: server closed the connection unexpectedly This probably means the server terminated abnormally before or while processing the request.]

Comment: Did you tried to connect manually to the database?

Comment: how will i do that? i'm new in symfony and postgres @zilongqiu

Comment: You can follow this tutorial http://www.postgresqltutorial.com/ (not tested)

Comment: oh thanks! i'll give it a try. @zilongqiu